# Insights for pages that have been liked

Tags: facebook-graph-api

So I would think this would be an easy thing to do, but I'm completely lost right now. I have a website. It has a facebook page. That fb page has a bunch of likes and all is good. We also have the "like" button on various webpages throughout our website. If I go to those webpages individually, I can see how many people have hit the like button, but I have not found any where to see some reports. Ideally, I'd like to see:

1. The most popular (liked) webpages on our website
2. The total number of interactions (likes) across my domain
3. The same basic demographic information that is available for our fb page

We have had the like button integrated for a few months now, but I'm not sure if it should be linked to our fb page or if I have to create a custom app to associate it with. Right now we have it assigned to our fb page.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible, but requires a few steps:

- Claim insights for your domain: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/insights/#claiming_a_domain
- Grab your domain ID: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/domain/
- Access insights using the graph API

Comment: Julien, this is exactly what I was looking for. Now if I can bug you with one last question: How do I grant the permissions I need (read_insights)? I don't know if I'm supposed to grant that to my personal account, if I have to create an app specifically for this or what. The docs seem thorough (and maybe its just me), but they seem to glance over the "how" to grant permissions.

Comment: To access insights,  you need to grant the read_insights permission. In that case, you'd need to grant that permission to yourself, in order to obtain an access_token that will let you call the proper API. The easiest way to do that is to use the FB.login() method from the JS SDK. http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.login/. Mail me if you need help with that.

Comment: But what part of the insights table do you grab to glean this information??

Comment: Grab all of them, save them in a database, and filter later using SQL: https://graph.facebook.com/app_id/insights?access_token=...